# OSX app icon and name changed while running

Tags: java, macos, javafx-2, osx-mavericks

I hav a Java 7 app that has jre bundled by mvn:jfx to run as a self-contained Map App. Just like usual, It has its own icon ans name (set in  Contents/Info.plist).
When I start the App, everything is normal, the icon (defined by CFBundleIconFile) and App name (defined by CFBundleName) show nicely in the dock and in the 'cmd+tab row'. But:

Sometimes, after leaving the app run for 2-3 days and putting my macbook to sleep for a coule of times, suddenly, both dock and cmd+tab-row show generic binary / terminal icon instead (see screenshot). Also, the name of the app has changed to the name of the executable (defined by CFBundleExecutable). The App bundle itself in the Applications/ folder still shows the right icon.

After restarting the app, usually it is back to normal.
Except when OSX was restarted (due to some installer) with reopening all windows, It reopened right back to the broken state.

http://files.heikohaller.de/missing-app-icon.png

Any ideas what could cause this or where I could even continue to investigate?

jdk1.7.0_55.jdk
OSX 10.9.3

Comment: Unfortunately no answer, but can you reproduce the "broken state" at will, by killing/restarting the Dock process while your app is running?

Comment: Cannot test right now, because my MacBook pro died :( Will report back later...